# Ubuntu/Kubuntu 14.04 LTS can't boot on a Nvidia Optimus Laptop

Tags: boot, 14.04, nouveau

I am unable to boot Ubuntu/Kubuntu 14.04 LTS on Thinkpad T420i with Nvidia Optimus enabled. System boots to a blank screen. System also slowly turns into a furnace. Temperature would read close to 100C or maximum for the system.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to go into BIOS and disable Nvidia Optimus, should fix your problem.

Here's another thread relating to your topic:[Nvidia Optimus Issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059854)

Comment: My system working fine with U/Kubuntu 12.04 including installation. So after two years of work we have been able to break an LTS release. This is sad.